# Gmail authentication error: invalid_request Missing required parameter: client_id

Tags: r, authentication, google-authentication, gmailr

I am facing an issue while trying to access gmail through gmailr package.

Had given then input for Client and secret_key and it is able to run gmail_auth(..........). However, when I am trying to extract messages() I am getting 400 error.

Tried using .json secret_file as well. But same result! 
Can you explain where I am missing the client_id?

```
  gmail_auth(scope = c("read_only", "modify", "compose", "full"), id = the$id,secret = the$secret, secret_file = NULL)

 messages(search="XX",num_results = 2, label_ids = NULL,include_spam_trash = FALSE,page_token = NULL, user_id = "me")
```

400. That’s an error.

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Missing required parameter: client_id

Learn more

Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose https://mail.google.com/
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
response_type=code